# C# mvc5 - Easy way to check if user is authenticated in each controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller that I only want authenticated users to be able to access. Do I have to put a check in each method in my controller to verify a user is authenticated, or is there another way to handle this? Can I use annotations to do this instead?

Example from my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (UserVerified())
            {
               ...
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }

    public ActionResult FacebookLogin()
    {
        if (UserVerified())
        {
           ....
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }

    private bool UserVerified()
    {
        if (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use AuthorizeAttribute for it.
Put it to every action.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult FacebookLogin()
{
}
```

It will do the whole work for you. It checks whether the currect user is authenticated. If he is authenticated - proceeds to the action, if he is not - returns to the home page.

You can also add this attribute to a controller. Then all actions will require authorization.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult FacebookLogin()
    {
    }
}
```

**Update:** And, yes, as Kamil said. Read this article, please.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

You spend some time now and will spend much less time having questions about ASP.NET authentication in future.

By the way, you don't need to check for

```
User != null && User.Identity != null
```

If you are using default authentication then you can be always sure that `User.Identity` is a proper object. You can access `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` directly.

Answer (score 8):

Using  `Authorize` attribute is way to go (already answered here). In addition, if you may want to implement some other business rules or filtering checks, you can create a filter class inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute.

e.g.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeFilter: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false; //User not Authorized
        }

        else
        {
             //Check your conditions here
        }
     }
}
```

Then decorate your controller or Action as:

```
[CustomAuthorizeFilter]
public class SomeController
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either user `[Authorize]` attribute which is inbuilt. Or you can develop your custom attribute for the same purpose.

You can start from here for your own attribute:

[Create custom attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)

If you want to perform validation on each action method, then put that attribute on `Controller` level rather than each action method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[Authorize]` attribute above controller methods.

Please follow this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the authentication rules to apply to all controller actions you can do this:

```
[someAuthAttribute]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   // pseudo
    public ActionResult Index() {
       return response;
    }

    public ActionResult FacebookLogin(){
       return response;
    }

}
```

Where Index() and FacebookLogin() will adhere to the authentication rules of [someAuthAttribute]. You can also use this "hierarchy" to apply more specific rules to your action methods. Like this:

```
[someAuthAttribute]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   // pseudo
    public ActionResult Index() {
       return response;
    }

    [someFBAuthAttribute]
    public ActionResult FacebookLogin(){
       return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit authorization from a base controller.

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Domain\Group")]
public class BaseController : Controller

public class ChildController : BaseController
```